# Parsing JSON file to get list inside list

Tags: dart, flutter, nested-lists

I'm working in flutter which it should read from Json file list with object, I want to create  list inside list where the first list will give the subject and the body, and then it should go to another list of that specific suject and give also a list where each have the measurements, but this error appears

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:test_app/InspectionDetail.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';


class InspetionList extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'inspection-list';
  @override
  _InspetionListState createState() => _InspetionListState();
}

class _InspetionListState extends State<InspetionList> {
  List<Lists> info = [];
  List <Lists> _search =[];
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();



  Future <Lists>  _getLists() async {
    final data = await http.get(
        "https://api.myjson.com/bins/qiulc");
    List jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    for (int u =0; u < jsonData.length ; u++ ) {
    //  print(jsonData[u]["subject"]);
      print(jsonData[u]["name"]);
      return (jsonData[u]["subject"]);

    }

  }

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    fetch();
  }
  Future <List> future;
//Future <String> future ;

  void fetch() async{
    future = _getLists() as Future<List>;

  }

  onSearch(String text) async {
    _search.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }
  }
 //  info.forEach((f){
 //    if(f.body.contains(text) || f.subject.contains(text)) _search.add(f);
 //  });
 //  setState(() {

 //  });
 //

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
     title: new Text("List of projects"),
     ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Column(
       children: <Widget>[
          new FutureBuilder(
              future: _getLists(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
               if(snapshot.hasData){
                 return ListView.builder(
                 itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return
                      ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Icon(Icons.settings_input_antenna),
                        ),
                        title: Text(snapshot.data[index]["subject"]),
                        subtitle: Text(''),
                      );
                 ListTile(
                   title: Text(snapshot.data[index]["subject"]),
                 );}
                  );
                }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                  return new Text("Error ${snapshot.error}");
                }
              })
        ],
      ),
    )
   );
  }
}




class Lists {
  final String subject;
  final String body;
  Inspection name;

  Lists({
    this.subject,
    this.name,
    this.body
  });

  factory Lists.fromJson(Map parsedJson){
    return Lists(
        subject: parsedJson['subject'],
        body: parsedJson['body'],
        name: Inspection.fromJson(parsedJson['name'])
    );
  }
}
class Inspection{
  final String Lwidth;
  final String Twidth;
  final String height;
  final String circumfernce;
  Inspection({
   this.Lwidth,
   this.Twidth,
   this.circumfernce,
   this.height
 });
 factory Inspection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
   return Inspection(
       Lwidth: json['Lwidth'],
       Twidth: json['Twidth'],
       height: json['height'],
       circumfernce: json['circumfernce']
   );
 }}


Error :

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Lists>'
E/flutter (19254): #0      _InspetionListState._getLists (package:test_app/InspectionList.dart:45:7)
E/flutter (19254): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19254): #1      _InspetionListState.fetch (package:test_app/InspectionList.dart:59:14)
E/flutter (19254): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19254): #2      _InspetionListState.initState (package:test_app/InspectionList.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (19254): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:58)
E/flutter (19254): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)
E/flutter (19254): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (19254): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (19254): #7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (19254): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (19254): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (19254): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (19254): #11     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (19254): #12     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter (19254): #13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)
E/flutter (19254): #14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (19254): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (19254): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (19254): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (19254): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (19254): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (19254): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (19254): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (19254): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (19254): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (19254): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (19254): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
E/flutter (19254): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
```

and here the Json file

```
[{"body":"for test","subject":"KSA","name":{"circumfernce":"33c","Twidth":"6c","height":"55c","Lwidth":"22c"}},{"body":"for test1","subject":"USA","name":{"circumfernce":"313c","Twidth":"61c","height":"515c","Lwidth":"212c"}},{"body":"for test2","subject":"UAE","name":{"circumfernce":"333c","Twidth":"36c","height":"535c","Lwidth":"232c"}}]
```

Comment: hey have you got the solution of your problem? I am also facing the similar problem how to handle list inside a list in json. If found can you please help?